# generate persian letters

Tags: javascript, php, html

i just want a php code to generate all persian letters

Comment: You have 32 persian letters. Just put them into an array and return the list?

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what you mean to do but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) and [this](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF) might be helpful if you want to use persian/arabic letters.

Comment: i just want a php code to generate all persian letters